¿Cómo se puede crear una variable en CSS?
Se puede agregar porque solo quiero agregarle colores a una letra.
Es decir que palabra "seis" quiero que cada letra sea un color como
puedo hacer???

Bienvenida al sitio., te sugerimos agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revia [ask], saludos-

El título de la pregunta no tiene que ver con el planteamiento; sin embargo, te voy a responder desde el punto de vista de este último.
Si solo tienes conocimiento de CSS y la palabra no la generas de forma dinámica, sino fija, te puede dar una idea con este ejemplo:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Colores en letras</title>
    <style>
        .coloresIndividuales {
            font-size: 40px;
            font-weight: bold;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .letraRoja {
            color: orange;
        }

        .letraAmarilla {
            color: yellow;
        }

        .letraVerde {
            color: green;
        }

        .letraAzul {
            color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="coloresIndividuales">
        <span class="letraRoja">S</span>
        <span class="letraAmarilla">e</span>
        <span class="letraVerde">i</span>
        <span class="letraAzul">s</span>
    </div>
</body>

</html>

Por otro lado, si las palabras no son fijas, sino dinámicas y conoces de JavaScript puedes hacerlo de este forma:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Colores en letras</title>
    <style>
        .coloresIndividuales {
            font-size: 40px;
            font-weight: bold;
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="coloresIndividuales" id="palabra">Seis</div>
    <script>

        var palabraElemento = document.getElementById("palabra");
        var palabra = palabraElemento.textContent.trim();
      
        palabraElemento.innerHTML = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < palabra.length; i++) {
            var letra = palabra[i];
            var span = document.createElement("span");
            span.textContent = letra;
            switch (i % 4) {
                case 0:
                    span.style.color = "orange";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    span.style.color = "yellow";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    span.style.color = "green";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    span.style.color = "blue";
                    break;
            }
            palabraElemento.appendChild(span);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>

